# Comprehensive resource on diazo coupling?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am starting to do research on diazo coupling reactions and am looking for a book or literature review that is a comprehensive exploration of everything diazo coupling.

I found one book which is pretty amazing: https://ia802302.us.archive.org/8/items/aromaticdiazocom031270mbp/aromaticdiazocom031270mbp.pdf

It has a whole chapter devoted just to diazo coupling with various classes of compounds like phenols, amines, phenolic ethers, hydrocarbons, etc (which is exactly what I am looking for).  **BUT**, it's from the 1930's! It is quite challenging to read because it mostly describes reactions rather than showing them pictorially. Also, some of the theory is a bit dated!

My question: Does anyone know of a more ***modern*** resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer books as secondary reference, the *The chemistry of diazonium and diazo groups* in the Patai series (back 1978) may be one source.  More recently, the two books about diazochemistry by Zollinger, 1994 [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/3527601724) and [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/3527601732).

Maybe not as comprehensive as the two sources above, but offering an overview are Merino's critical review about diazocoupling reactions in *Chem. Soc. Rev.* ([doi 10.1039/C0CS00183J](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2011/cs/c0cs00183j#!divAbstract)) in 2011, and Oger's overview about their application in flow chemistry in *Organic Chemistry Frontiers* ([doi 10.1039/C5QO00037H](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2015/QO/C5QO00037H#!divAbstract)) in 2015.